# Can BLUNO receive iBeacon signal and determine the distance?

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, bluno

I'm trying to make a project where BLUNO will act as the receiver of BLE signal. An event (Buzz, LCD, vibration, etc..) will be activated when the iBeacon gets out of range. 
I already have the BLUNO with the latest software. I will buy an iBeacon with Apple standards. For now I'm using an iPhone to simulate it.

I want to confirm if BLUNO can act as a receiver rather than an iBeacon itself.

How can I receive the RSSI and derive distance from it? Any libraries or sources?

Answer (score 0):

The BLUNO cannot receive iBeacon signals, it can only send iBeacon advertisements.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I dig deeper into their documentation. There is a CENTRAL setting and a PERIPHERAL setting. Using the CENTRAL settings it can connect to other iBeacons. I got some response through the AT commands. My problem now is to write an Arduino Code that uses these RSSI data that I get from the AT commands. Any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

BLUNO is based on the TI CC2540, which can scan for bluetooth devices if flashed with custom firmware.  I am not aware of any custom firmware that is designed to send beacon scan results from the BLUNO, but in theory it should be possible if you are willing to dig down deep and write your own firmware.

RedBear Labs has a couple of decent firmware examples for the CC2540 including ones that do scanning:

https://redbearlab.zendesk.com/entries/72966016-BLE-Mini-Tutorials

See here for how to flash custom firmware on the CC2540 using BLUNO:

http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_SKU:DFR0267#Update_BLE_Firmware_on_Bluno.EF.BC.88AT.2BVERSION_to_check_the_version.EF.BC.89

Comment: I don't need to scan for it. I already know the MAC address I want to connect to. I just wish to get the RSSI from that Specific iBeacon I can connect it through AT+BIND.